# Creating pages automatically

Tags: php, html, web, content-management-system

I want to create a new html page automatically when a user signs in and posts something (Like the ones which are created when someone posts a question here in stackoverflow). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you will have to learn is:

- php
- mysql

To get yourself started, learn how to create a [database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_db.asp) and [tables](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) in mysql. 
After that you i'll have to learn how to [insert your information into a database with php.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)
You probably also want people to [registrer themself and login.](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal)

At the end you'll need to grap the content by id from your database and print it to your php file. This can be done by adding a variable to your url.

Example:

**localhost/index.php?post=1**

Now you can grab your 'post id' or whatever with [$_GET["id"]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score -1):

To generate a HTML page :

```
  $filename = 'test.html';
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```